# OneDrive API. moving a file to a root of an account. Doesn't work

Tags: onedrive

I try to use onedrive REST API to manage my files

I want to move file. Move operation works for all cases except "move to root". If i move to some folder then all is fine. If i want to move root then i use the "me/skydrive" as the ID of the folder. but it doesn't work

example,

MOVE https://apis.live.net/v5.0/file.68b01a2d7f7f7d7c.68B01A2D7F7F7D7C!39188

```
(
    [destination] => me/skydrive
)
```

Response

```
{
   "error": {
      "code": "request_parameter_invalid", 
      "message": "The value of input resource ID parameter 'destination' isn't valid. The expected value for this parameter is a resource ID for one of these types: 'folder'."
   }
}
```

how to solve this? what should be the 'destination'

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use the folder id for the root drive to move the file.  To find the folder id for the root drive, make a GET request for "me/skydrive".  The JSON response will return the id that you will want to use for the MOVE request.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add some official sources to the answer:

> **Note:** When moving items to the root of a OneDrive you cannot use the `"id:" "root"` syntax. You either need to use the real ID of the
>   root folder, or use `{"path": "/drive/root"}` for the parent reference.

Source: https://dev.onedrive.com/items/move.htm